# Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Использую код для слайдера! Слайдер работает, но на других страница в консоле ошибка (Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined), помогите пожалуйста исправить

код слайдера

```
var slideIndex = 1;

// Функция увеличивает индекс на 1, показывает следующй слайд
function plusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
}

// Функция уменьшяет индекс на 1, показывает предыдущий слайд
function minusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);  
}

// Устанавливает текущий слайд
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

var element = document.getElementsByClassName('products-slider-wrapper');

    showSlides(slideIndex);
    // Основная функция слайдера 
    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("products-slider-wrapper-item");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("products-slider-dots-item");



        if (n > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length
        }

        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].classList.add("hidden-slide");

        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" products-slider-dots-active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("hidden-slide");
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " products-slider-dots-active";
    }
```

Comment: на других страницах каких? похоже вы пытаетесь вызвать слайдер там, где его нет

Answer (score 2):

В начало функции добавьте проверку на наличие слайдера

```
if ($('.products-slider-wrapper-item').length === 0) return;
```

Comment: а на чисто js как это сделать? Через document.queryselectorAll?

Comment: @Владислав Донченко, Да, заменяете `$` на `document.queryselectorAll` и всё. Хотяя... чтобы оно корректно работало - достаточно ведь наличия только одного класса? Тогда можно использовать `if( !document.queryselector('.products-slider-wrapper-item') ) { return; }` — символ `!` означат отрицание условия. Если на странице есть хотя бы один такой класс, `document.queryselector('...')` вернет true (отрицание = false). Поэтому если этот класс существует - return не сработает.

Comment: спасибо большое, проблема решена!

Answer (score 1):

На других страницах нет таких элементов

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("products-slider-wrapper-item");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("products-slider-dots-item");
```

Поэтому при обращении к несуществующим элементам возникает ошибка

```
slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("hidden-slide");
dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " products-slider-dots-active";
```

Comment: а как убрать ошибку, на других страницах и не должно быть тех елементов!

Comment: добавьте проверку на наличие этих элементов. желательно перед выполнением всего что связано со слайдером

Comment: а можете пожалуйста сказать как я в jq знаю что можно сделать проверку через .is() а мне нужно на чистом не знаю как сделать?